# Node.js: require in REPL?

Tags: node.js

Why require in REPL doesn't use cache from main context and requires file again?

Example:
test.js:

```
var repl = require('repl');
global.a = require('./a');
repl.start({
  prompt: "node via stdin> ",
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
```

a.js

```
console.log(1)
```

I'm starting test.js:

```
node test.js
```

It print's "1"

when i print "require('./a')" in REPL:

```
node via stdin> var aInREPL = require('./a')
```

and it prints "1" again, and so, global.a !== aInREPL

But sometimes I need to get in REPL same object as in main program (for example Singletone). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the required code (object, function, ..) to the REPL's context:

```
var repl = require('repl');
repl.start({
  prompt: "node via stdin> ",
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
}).context.a = require('./a.js');
```

Now it will print 1 only once =) or add global to REPL's context

Comment: it's inconvenient. I can use require.main in REPL to get same context

Comment: This approach can and will be much cleaner than require.main. Above is just a terse example (not the prettiest). 1) It's much more explicit 2) Cleaner, set the whole context object once and you don't have to go digging through requires 3) More flexible, you can add things outside requires (constructor args etc)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box the REPL runs in a different context (see [repl.start](http://www.nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options) function for details).

Basically, you have two options to share your global context with the newly started REPL:

- You can provide the `useGlobal: true` option in your call to `start`.
- You can attach external objects to the REPL's `context` property.

Which way is preferred depends on what you want to achieve: Do you want to share *anything*, then go with `useGlobal`. If you only want to share selected objects, use the `context` property and only assign those objects you want to share (see Scott's post for an example).

Comment: with "useGlobal: true" I have same behavior